# Empty arrays error

Tags: php, arrays

i have a set of php arrays, and i am trying to retrieve those details and echo. however i get errors such as `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.
how can i rectify such errors from appearing? 
this problem occurs when i echo all cakes from all users.

I have tried so far to eliminate possible errors from the code and also used validation statements such as `if empty` then do this, however the problem still persists.

```
<?php 
//USERS ARRAYS
$users = array();
$users["john"] = array(
    "first name" => "John",
    "last name" => "Smith",
    "address" => "London");
$users["jade"] = array(
    "first name" => "Jade",
    "last name" => "Anthony",
    "address" => "Essex");
$users["clement"] = array(
    "first name" => "Clement",
    "last name" => "Smith",
    "address" => "Essex");

//CAKES ARRAY
$cakes = array();
$cakes = array(
    "john" => array(
        "Chocolate Cake" => array(
                    "ingredients" => "chocolate, flour, eggs",
                    "cooking time" => "20 minutes"),
        ),
    "jade" => array(
        "Lemon Cheesecake" => array(
                    "ingredients" => "lemons, flour, eggs",
                    "cooking time" => "30 minutes")),
    "clement" => NULL,
);
?>
<?php $user_name = 'john';?>
<h1>Name</h1>
    <p><?php echo $users["first name"]; ?></p>

<h1>Cakes Made</h1>
<?php
foreach($cakes[$user_name] as $key => $val)
 { echo $key . " <strong>Ingredients: </strong>" . $val["ingredients"] . "<br>"; }

    ?>
<h1>All cakes from all users</h1>

<?php foreach($cakes as $cake)  {  ?>

<?php if(is_array($cake)) {
foreach($cake as $cakemade => $newval)
  if(empty($cakemade)) { echo "";} else
 { echo $cakemade . "<strong>" . $newval['ingredients'] ."</strong> <br>"; }
?>
<?php }} ?>
```

your input is welcome. :)

edit: Just to be clear the code error relates to the second part of the code in which it displays all cakes from all users.

Comment: try `if(count($array)>0)` before the foreach

Comment: Only `foreach()` `if` `$cakes[$user_name]` `isset()`?

Comment: @Ronser If `foreach()` fails because `$array` isn't an array, then so will `count()`.

Comment: `if(is_array($array)){ 
    foreach($array...)`

Comment: for readability you shouldn't close and open the `?> <?php` tags if you don't have to

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the variable in want use in foreach is set

```
if(isset($cakes[$user_name]) && count($cakes[$user_name]) > 0)
  foreach($cakes[$user_name] as $key => $val) {}
```

Comment: suppose if there were not any values in the array (not even null), would it simply ignore or would it show an error?

Answer (score 0):

Missing `"`s for the `keys`.Your array should be -

```
$cakes = array(
    "john" => array(
        "Chocolate Cake" => array(
                    "ingredients" => "chocolate, flour, eggs",
                    "cooking time" => "20 minutes"),
        )
    "jade" => array(
        "Lemon Cheesecake" => array(
                    "ingredients" => "lemons, flour, eggs",
                    "cooking time" => "30 minutes"),
    "clement" => NULL,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($variable) && count($variable) > 0) {
     foreach($variable as $key => $value) {
        //Your code
     }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way would be to check if the variable is an array and then check if it's empty.
As you have made clear if the variable is array and it's not empty, then you should waste processor time  to iterate over an array.

So the code would look like this:

```
if(!empty($var) && is_array($var)) {
    foreach($var as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' => ' . $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many syntax errors in your pasted code. also use `is_array()` to check an array.
also you have defined `$username = "john"` and passing in foreach with `$user_name`
try

```
<?php 
//USERS ARRAYS
$users = array();
$users["john"] = array(
    "first name" => "John",
    "last name" => "Smith",
    "address" => "London");
$users["jade"] = array(
    "first name" => "Jade",
    "last name" => "Anthony",
    "address" => "Essex");
$users["clement"] = array(
    "first name" => "Clement",
    "last name" => "Smith",
    "address" => "Essex");

//CAKES ARRAY
$cakes = array();
$cakes = array(
    "john" => array(
        "Chocolate Cake" => array(
                    "ingredients" => "chocolate, flour, eggs",
                    "cooking time" => "20 minutes"),
        ),
    "jade" => array(
        "Lemon Cheesecake" => array(
                    "ingredients" => "lemons, flour, eggs",
                    "cooking time" => "30 minutes")),
    "clement" => NULL,
);
?>
<?php $user_name = 'john';?>
<h1>Name</h1>
    <p><?php echo $users["first name"]; ?></p>

<h1>Cakes Made</h1>
<?php
foreach($cakes[$user_name] as $key => $val)
 { echo $key . " <strong>Ingredients: </strong>" . $val["ingredients"] . "<br>"; }

    ?>
<h1>All cakes from all users</h1>

<?php foreach($cakes as $cake)  {  ?>

<?php if(is_array($cake)) {
foreach($cake as $cakemade => $newval)
  if(empty($cakemade)) { echo "";} else
 { echo $cakemade . "<strong>" . $newval['ingredients'] ."</strong> <br>"; }
?>
<?php }} ?>
```